# how to update tk.label from receiving text from active tcp session

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am trying to update the text in a tk.label from active tcp session that is working as a server.
So the script is actually waiting (server) to receive some text from a client via tcp connection.

```
import re
import socketserver
import socket
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import time

line = ""

class Info:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label=tk.Label(master)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label.configure(text='Ready to roll...')
        self.count = 0
        if self.count == 0: self.first_label()
        else: self.update_label()

    def first_label(self):
        self.label.configure(text=line_info)
        self.label.after(5000, self.update_label)
        self.count += 1

    def update_label(self):
        self.label.configure(text = line_info)
        self.label.after(5000, self.update_label) # call this method again in 1,000 milliseconds
        self.count += 1
        with socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), MyTCPHandler) as server:
            print("{}:{} - READY".format(host, port))
            # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
            # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
            server.serve_forever()

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        data = self.data.decode('utf-8')

        # Do string manipulation to find cpu/gpu and co.

        line_info = "{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(timestamp, tcpu, tgpu, cpu, core, volt, gpu)
        print(line_info)
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(bytes("OK", "utf-8"))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    bashCmd = "hostname -I | awk -F\" \" '{print $1}'"
    data = subprocess.check_output(["bash", "-c", bashCmd]).strip()
    server_ip = data.decode('utf-8')

    host, port = server_ip, 9999

    line_info = "Updating..."

    root = tk.Tk()
    Info(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This server.py script is just waiting to receive some text from client via tcp, example:

```
10/12/2020 10:50:01 [192.168.1.124] CPU=54.61C GPU=55.10C CPU=700GHz Core=400MHz Core=1.35V GPU=300MHz  OK
10/12/2020 10:50:12 [192.168.1.124] CPU=54.61C GPU=55.10C CPU=700GHz Core=400MHz Core=1.35V GPU=300MHz  OK
10/12/2020 10:50:23 [192.168.1.124] CPU=54.61C GPU=55.10C CPU=700GHz Core=400MHz Core=1.35V GPU=300MHz  OK
```

My goal is to take this text received via tcp connection and view it into the tk-window as label text that will scroll. Although the tcp connection and the text is received from the client to the server and the tk window is initialized it never get updated with the new information (variable line_info) that is coming every 20s from the client. For check, i just print line_info to stdout after the string manipulation.

[image: Tk-window with label initial text]

How can I update the text in tk.label?

Comment: You create new TCPServer instance in every execution of `update_label()` and call `serve_forever()` which is a blocking function.

Comment: yeah, I know but how else shall I do this? If I remove the `server.serve_forever()` then the tcp connection is not working and nothing is received from the client! So, how to do that or where to move the `server.serve_forever()` or even the `with` command!

Comment: You can running `update_label()` in a thread but need to remove those `after(...)` statements.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your suggestion. Can you be more clear or add an answer with a working example or so? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You better use thread to run `update_label()` so that it won't block the application:

```py
import socketserver
import socket
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class Info:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label=tk.Label(master, textvariable=line_info)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        threading.Thread(target=self.update_label, daemon=True).start()

    def update_label(self):
        line_info.set('Ready to roll...')
        with socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), MyTCPHandler) as server:
            print("{}:{} - READY".format(host, port))
            server.serve_forever()

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            data = self.data.decode('utf-8')

            # Do string manipulation to find cpu/gpu and co.

            line_info.set("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(timestamp, tcpu, tgpu, cpu, core, volt, gpu))
            print(line_info.get())
            # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
            self.request.sendall(bytes("OK", "utf-8"))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    bashCmd = "hostname -I | awk -F\" \" '{print $1}'"
    data = subprocess.check_output(["bash", "-c", bashCmd]).strip()
    server_ip = data.decode('utf-8')

    host, port = server_ip, 9999

    root = tk.Tk()
    line_info = tk.StringVar()
    Info(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have changed `line_info` to `StringVar()`.